# Match single quotes from python re

Tags: python

How to match the following i want all the names with in the single quotes

```
This hasn't been much that much of a twist and turn's to 'Tom','Harry' and u know who..yes its 'rock'
```

How to extract the name within the single quotes only

```
name = re.compile(r'^\'+\w+\'')
```

Comment: Basic regular expressions stuff. `^` matches start of line/string.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The following regex finds all single words enclosed in quotes:

```
In [6]: re.findall(r"'(\w+)'", s)
Out[6]: ['Tom', 'Harry', 'rock']
```

Here:

- the `'` matches a single quote;
- the `\w+` matches one or more word characters;
- the `'` matches a single quote;
- the parentheses form a *capture group*: they define the part of the match that gets returned by `findall()`.

If you only wish to find words that start with a capital letter, the regex can be modified like so:

```
In [7]: re.findall(r"'([A-Z]\w*)'", s)
Out[7]: ['Tom', 'Harry']
```

Comment: As names usually have more than one or two characters i additionally propose to use (\w{3:}) instead of (\w+), which means "three or more".

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest

```
r = re.compile(r"\B'\w+'\B")
apos = r.findall("This hasn't been much that much of a twist and turn's to 'Tom','Harry' and u know who..yes its 'rock'")
```

Result:

```
>>> apos
["'Tom'", "'Harry'", "'rock'"]
```

The "negative word boundaries" (`\B`) prevent matches like the `'n'` in words like `Rock'n'Roll`.

**Explanation:**

```
\B  # make sure that we're not at a word boundary
'   # match a quote
\w+ # match one or more alphanumeric characters
'   # match a quote
\B  # make sure that we're not at a word boundary
```

Answer (score 1):

`^` ('hat' or 'caret', among other names) in regex means "start of the string" (or, given particular options, "start of a line"), which you don't care about. Omitting it makes your regex work fine:

```
>>> re.findall(r'\'+\w+\'', s)
["'Tom'", "'Harry'", "'rock'"]
```

The regexes others have suggested might be better for what you're trying to achieve, this is the minimal change to fix your problem.

Comment: @burhan that too, yes; I'll update the answer to include it. In my experience, 'hat' is more common but I can agree to disagree with Wikipedia. :-)

Answer (score -1):

Your regex can only match a pattern following the start of the string. Try something like: `r"'([^']*)'"`

Comment: That will give you `'t been much that much of a twist and turn'` on the provided sample.